# asp.net Access to the path XXX is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, io, directory

I've read tons of articles about this error.. also trying to set the folder's permission to the lowest:

[image]

But I still getting the error: Access to the path '\servername\shareFolder$\folderNameWeWantToCreate' is denied.

I am trying to check whether a directory exists and try to create a directory if not using the below code:

```
string Folderpath = @"\\servername\shareFolder$\folderNameWeWantToCreate";
   if (!Directory.Exists(FolderPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath);
```

The above code works well on local, but the error comes out when put on to the server.

Is there anything I did wrong??

Comment: Get full access for this parent folder to group IIS_IUSRS

Comment: You could also try adding full access to the IUSR user. That usually works for me.

Comment: Are you using IIS or IIS Express (the default one that comes with Visual Studio)?

Comment: @RaduPorumb I am using IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to impersonate identity for user

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions:

#### Application Pool Identity

You need to create a new Application Pool in IIS that runs as the LocalSystem user and change your application to run on that AppPool. You need a high privilege user to do stuff on the local HD anyway and this'll save you a lot of permission slinging. In the future if you want to harden security you can always go back to a low privilege AppPool and just grant it permissions wherever it needs them.

#### Remote User Impersonation

If the above doesn't work, this is your recourse. It seems tricky but the code I'm running works perfectly on ASP.NET MVC 5 / .NET 4.5.1 so it should run fine on older versions too. Here's the code:

Helper classes:

```
public class ImpersonationHelper
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1;

    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3;
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

    public static SafeTokenHandle GetSafeTokenHandle(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;

        bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domain, password,
            LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50,
            out safeTokenHandle);

        if (false == returnValue)
        {
            int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
        }

        return safeTokenHandle;
    }
}

public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private SafeTokenHandle()
        : base(true)
    {
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}
```

Main code:

```
var remoteUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RemoteUser"];
var remotePassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RemotePassword"];
var remoteDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RemoteDomain"];
var safeTokenHandle = ImpersonationHelper.GetSafeTokenHandle(remoteUser, remotePassword, remoteDomain);

using (safeTokenHandle)
{
    using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
    {
        using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
        {
            // do stuff here the same as you would locally
        }
    }
 }
```